# only one item from the array usersubids is rendered to the display

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

When I fetch data using subdata and set the state using usersubids, i only see one item in the array

```
  useEffect(()=>{
      fetchSubData();
    
   },[])

  async function fetchSubData(){
    
    //setLoading(true);
    await firestore().collection('users').where('uid','==',auth().currentUser.uid).get()
   .then(async (querySnapshot) => {
       
        await querySnapshot.forEach(async(documentSnapshot) => { 
        
           await  documentSnapshot.data().subreddits.forEach(async subid=>{
                await firestore().collection('subreddits').doc(subid).get()
               .then(doc=>{
                    setUserSubIds([...usersubids,{title:doc.data().title,id:doc.id}]);
                    console.log({title:doc.data().title,id:doc.id})
                })

            })
        
        
        })
        
     })
   }
```

**this is the code for rendering from usersubids**

```
    const itempickerchildren=(usersubids.map((item)=><Picker.Item label={item.title} key=
       {item.id} value={item.id}/>))
```

Comment: it is usersubids instead of usersubarr in setUserSubIds([...usersubsarr,{title:doc.data().title,id:doc.id}]);